# Block event invites from a page on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events

I get invited to events of clubs all the time and those clubs have "pages" on Facebook (that I never liked) that cannot be blocked like those from individuals.

Does anyone know how to block pages from inviting you to events?

This is not the same as for apps or friends inviting you to stuff, because for these two cases there are easy blocking features. I am referring to the Facebook pages, as many companies have (which normally people "like" in order to subscribe to their updates in your newsfeed). Now this page is inviting me to events all the time, but I have never "liked" it.

Comment: This question has already been answered here:

http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25313/39904